# Binomial transform

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

how can be prove  expression:

$\sum \limits_{s = 0}^{2k} (-1)^s\binom{n+s}{n}\binom{n+2k-s}{n} = \binom{n+k}{k}$

by using this identity:

$(1 − t)^{−n−1}(1 + t)^{−n−1}= (1 − t^2)^{−n−1},$

or
how can be prove  expression:

$\sum \limits_{s = 0}^{k} (-1)^{k-s}\binom{n}{s}\binom{m+k-s-1}{k-s} =\binom{n-m}{k}$

by using this identity:

$(1 + t)^n (1 + t)^{−m} = (1 + t)^{n−m}.$

I open brackets by Binomial Theorem, but
what kind of coefficients i should equate?

Comment: Find an expression for $\binom{-m}{k}$. Then look at the coefficients of $t^r$ in the expansions of both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Second problem)*

Using Upper Negation, followed by the Vandermonde Identity:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-s}{n \choose s}{m+k-s-1\choose k-s}&=\sum_{s=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-s}{n \choose s}{(-m+1)-1\choose k-s}(-1)^{k-s}\\
&=\sum_{s=0}^{k}\underbrace{(-1)^{2(k-s)}}_{1}{n \choose s}{-m\choose k-s}\\
&={n-m\choose k}\qquad \blacksquare 
\end{align}$$