# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} {n \choose i} {n-i-1 \choose k-i}=1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

Prove $\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} {n \choose i} {n-i-1 \choose k-i}=1$. I was recently working through the proof of a question using inclusion exclusion and was stuck on this part. I verified this equation with wolfram alpha.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1010738/573047) and there replace $s$ with $i$ and $m$ with $n-k$.

Comment: You can search formulas with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5Ek%20(-1)%5E%7Bk-i%7D%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20i%7D%20%7Bn-i-1%20%5Cchoose%20k-i%7D%3D1%24&p=1).